# Find the maximum key value pair from array of dict using python

Tags: python, dictionary, max

I have a list like:

```
[{"name":"john","age":40,"class":10},
 {"name":"john","age":45,"class":12},
 {"name":"sam","age":10,"class":5},
 {"name":"sam","age":11,"class":9},
 {"name":"mark","age":50,"class: 8"}]
```

I want to get maximum age for unique names. how can I do it using python?

My expected answer:

```
[{"name":"john","age":45,"class":12},
{"name":"sam","age":11,"class":9},
{"name":"mark","age":50,"class: 8"}]
```

Comment: Hint: `itertools.groupby`. What've you tried thus far?

Comment: You should at least be able to implement a straight forward solution using a dictionary and a `for` loop.

Comment: Okay, great. You've updated your question. But what have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to do this:

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [{"name":"john","age":40,"class":10},
        {"name":"john","age":45,"class":12},
        {"name":"sam","age":10,"class":5},
        {"name":"sam","age":11,"class":9},
        {"name":"mark","age":50,"class": 8}]

# groups dictionary by "name"
# takes max dictionary of each group by "age"
result = [max(list(g), key=lambda x: x['age']) for _, g in groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda x: x['name']), key=lambda x: x['name'])]

print(result)
```

Which outputs:

```
[{'name': 'john', 'age': 45, 'class': 12}, 
 {'name': 'sam', 'age': 11, 'class': 9}, 
 {'name': 'mark', 'age': 50, 'class': 8}]
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple for loop solution would be

```
A = [{"name":"john","age":40},
 {"name":"john","age":45},
 {"name":"sam","age":10},
 {"name":"sam","age":11},
 {"name":"mark","age":50}]


res = {}
for i in A:
    if i['name'] not in res:
        res[i['name']] = i['age']
    else:
        if res[i['name']] < i['age']:
            res[i['name']] = i['age']

print res
```

Result:

```
{'john': 45, 'sam': 11, 'mark': 50}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not preserve the original structure of the data (which may be important in most real cases).

Comment: it's pretty close.   result = {'john': 45, 'sam': 11, 'mark': 50}; newresult = [{"name":name, "age":result[name]} for name in result]

Comment: I have changed the questing a bit and added a new field and an excted answer format.

Answer (score 1):

Can you specify your specific goal a little further? Do you want to preserve the structure? Do you want a list for all names in the dictionary? 
You could write a function like this:

```
def maxdictlist(name,dictlist):
    maxlst = []
    for x in dictlist:
        if x["name"] == name:
            maxlst.append(x["age"])
    return max(maxlst)

print(maxdictlist("john",A))
```

which returns the max value for a given name.
If you're okay with saving a list of the names you're interested in and want to preserve the structure, you could also do something like this, using a key for the max function:

```
def ke(v,name):
    if v["name"] == name: return v["age"]
    else: return 0 #0 as default value

lst = []
names = ["john","sam"]
res = [max(A,key= lambda v:ke(v,name))) for name in names]

print(lst)
```

I would advise against this second method though.